# How to merge values of dictionaries with same key into one from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which looks like below

```
description = [{"category": "emergency", "meds": [{"drug": "mild", "env": "cold"}]},
               {"category": "normal", "meds": [{"drug": "slow", "env": "normal"}]},
               {"category": "emergency", "meds": [{"drug": "severe", "env": "hot"}]},
               {"category": "medium", "meds": [{"drug": "drowsy", "env": "normal"}]},
               {"category": "normal", "meds": [{"drug": "mild", "env": "normal"}]}]
```

As you can see for **category** key, `emergency` and `normal` comes twice. Now what I want is to merge the values of those two keys into one such that it looks like below

```
description_collapsed = [{"category": "emergency", "meds": [{"drug": "mild", "env": "cold"}, {"drug": "severe", "env": "hot"}]},
               {"category": "normal", "meds": [{"drug": "slow", "env": "normal"}, {"drug": "mild", "env": "normal"}]},
               {"category": "medium", "meds": [{"drug": "drowsy", "env": "normal"}]}]
```

I tried doing something like this

```
description_collapsed = {}
for i in description:
    if description_collapsed.get(i["category"]):
        description_collapsed.get(i["meds"].extend(i["meds"]))
    else:
        description_collapsed[i["category"]] = i["meds"]
```

But I only get one dictionary for the **meds** key of each category.

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: What is `i['rules']`? Don't you mean `i['meds']`?

Comment: @Barmar oh sorry typo..let me fix the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i['meds']` is not a key of `description_collapses`. The rules are the value of `description_collapsed.get(i["category"])`, so you need to extend that value.

You also had your parentheses wrong.

Note that your final result will be a dictionary, not a list.

```
description_collapsed = {}
for i in description:
    if i["category"] in description_collapsed:
        description_collapsed.[i["category"]].extend(i["meds"])
    else:
        description_collapsed[i["category"]] = i["meds"]
```